# How to prevent entering negative numbers in Kivymd MDTextField

Tags: python, python-3.x

In MDTextField, there is a restriction on entering only numbers, this is input_filter: "float", "int". But you can enter negative numbers

```
MDTextField:
    id: z1_m
    text:""
    hint_text: "z1"
    helper_text: "Число зубьев шестерни"                        
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    input_filter: "float"                                               
    on_text_validate: app.prochnjst()
```

Expected that when the user enters a minus sign, nothing happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reject Negative Numbers as exceptions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244588/reject-negative-numbers-as-exceptions-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try/ except:

```
try: 
  x = int(input())
  assert x > 0 
except AssertionError :
  print("Only positives are allowed")
```

Comment: Please tell me where should I add this exception to the code.